# Is the harm of uncommon drugs more feared than is justified?

Tags: drugs

I sometimes feel very cautious about the idea of taking a substance just because it is not culturally mainstream. It is much easier for people to say “We don’t know what the longterm effects are” about a substance they don’t trust. However, tobacco and alcohol are consumed heavily. They aren’t good for you. But people aren’t afraid of a little moderate use.

Is there any general finding that at the end of the day, all drugs probably have some longterm effect on the body, but the rarer drugs are not likely to be more harmful than the common ones?